# How to populate array from .TXT file without put any duplicates in the array?

Tags: java, arrays, duplicates, text-files

Basicaly need to scan this text file put it in to an array but i cant put any duplicates so it has to check the array and see if the array already contain that number, i cant use array list to do that.

My program puts in to an array put it put duplicates so how do i catch those duplicates to do something else with that and keep my array free of duplicates??

```
public static void readFromfile()throws IOException {


    int[] numbers = new int[500];
    int result, searchValue;

    int index = 0;

    // Open the file.
    File file = new File("file.txt");
    Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);
    int w = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<numbers.length; i++) {
        if (i==0 || numbers[i] != numbers[i-1]) {
            numbers[w++]=numbers[i];
            while(inputFile.hasNextInt() && index < numbers.length) {
                numbers[index] = inputFile.nextInt();
                Arrays.sort(numbers);
                System.out.println(numbers[index]);
                //index++;
            }

        }
    }

    // Close the file.
    inputFile.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you do not want duplicates then why don't you just use a Set: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Set.html

Comment: Is sorting one of your requirements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use TreeSet for unique and sorted list and convert it after reading file to an array:

```
    Set<Integer> set = new TreeSet<Integer>();
    while (inputFile.hasNextInt()) {
        int value = inputFile.nextInt();
        if (set.contains(value)) {
            // save value to dublicate's file
        }
        set.add(value);
    }
    Integer[] numbersInteger = set.toArray(new Integer[set.size()]);
```

The result `numbersInteger` will contain exactly the number of elements which are sorted and unique. There will be no empty elements and you don't have to define the size of array before reading file.

If you really need to have an array of `int` instead of `Integer` then you have to add these lines:

```
    int[] numbers = new int[numbersInteger.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < numbersInteger.length; i++) {
        numbers[i] = numbersInteger[i];
    }
```

Comment: and from there, how do i get the duplicates to write them to another file ?

Comment: To collect the dublicate values you have to test in while loop if (set.contains(value)) and write the current value to another file - added it in my answer

Answer (score 0):

The code can do a binary search if the array is sorted.  Using this in combination with a conditional if statement should determine whether the element should be inserted into the array.  Note that if the `binarySearch` does not find the element it will return a negative result.

```
public static void readFromfile() throws IOException {

    int[] numbers = new int[500];
    int result, searchValue;

    int index = 0;

    // Open the file.
    File file = new File("file.txt");
    Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);
    int w = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        if (i == 0 || numbers[i] != numbers[i - 1]) {
            numbers[w++] = numbers[i];
            while (inputFile.hasNextInt() && index < numbers.length) {
                int num = inputFile.nextInt();
                Arrays.sort(numbers);
                if(Arrays.binarySearch(numbers, num) < 0){
                    numbers[index] = inputFile.nextInt();
                }
                System.out.println(numbers[index]);
                // index++;
            }

        }
    }

    // Close the file.
    inputFile.close();
}
```

Comment: Just to insert an element it does not make sense to search for it every time.It could be restructured to use a set or a HashMap depending on the requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Set`. Every time you get a new number from your TXT file, you add it to the `Set` like this

```
Set s = new Set();
int tmp;
...
while(inputFile.hasNextInt() && index < numbers.length) {
    tmp = inputFile.newtInt();
    if (!s.contains(tmp)) {
        s.add(tmp);
        numbers[index] = tmp;
        Arrays.sort(numbers);
        System.out.println(numbers[index]);
        //index++;
    }
}
```

You should also consider moving `Arrays.sort(numbers);` out of the while loop.
Except if you need the array to be sorted at each step.